What are the exact guarantees of gRPC Streaming?
I've been having diffulty understanding the exact guarantees of gRPC streaming. Mostly because I have heard/read contradicting stories about it.
My question is the following:
If I have a stream [A, B, C] that Server X sends to Server Y, wheter that be in server side streaming, client side streaming or bidi streaming, Is it at all possible that:
Server Y only receives [A, C] but B is lost in a way that Server X or Server Y doesn't notice anything wrong?
The way I assumed it was that since http2 is built on TCP then all elements MUST be at least delivered to the kernel of Server Y. So absent a crash or the connection exploding I assumed it was not possible to lose an entire message.
But some colleagues have told me this is not the case, It is only guaranteed that they are in order but elements can be lost in the middle.
Can anyone shed some light about the exact delivery guarantees of gRPC streaming?
Any link to further reading about this would also be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!

Messages cannot be dropped from the middle.
gRPC's core concepts, architecture and lifecycle does say things of the sort:

gRPC guarantees message ordering within an individual RPC call.

I'd agree that says ordering, not "all messages are preserved." So I could understand that argument some. But in general, if something is dropped in gRPC that is an error. And if B is dropped, the error must be before C is delivered because the stream is in-order (so C is never delivered). The only out-of-order behavior in gRPC is cancellation.
You can view a stream as a message-based TCP connection, albeit with different close semantics (i.e., server can't half-close, which is the behavior people generally assume).
Note that if servers closes (OK or error) an RPC before all inbound messages are read in a client streaming RPC, those remaining inbound messages are dropped. But all the remaining messages are dropped, and the RPC itself is completed. So it isn't much of a surprising circumstance, other than gRPC allows the server to respond OK/success without having actually seen all the messages.
